# realloc 2D arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

I'm trying to increase a 2D array with malloc and realloc. I get a segmentation fault.

Here is how I create my tab:

```
char **tab2D = creerTab2D(taillex, tailley); 


char** creerTab2D(int taillex, int tailley) {

    char **tab2D = malloc( sizeof(char*) * taillex);

    for (int i = 0; i < taillex; i++) {
        tab2D[i] = creerTab1D(tailley);
    }

    return tab2D;
}
```

Here is how I increase his rows number by 1:

```
    (*taillex)++;

    *tab = (char**) realloc(*tab, *taillex * sizeof(char*)) ;

    if (*tab == NULL) { printf("Erreur lors du realloc\n"); return;}

    printf("%d", *taillex);

    *tab[*taillex] = malloc(*tailley * sizeof(char)); // Here is the bad access (segmentation fault)

    for (int i = 0; i < *tailley; i++) {
        (*tab)[*taillex][i] = '*';
        printf("%c", (*tab)[*taillex][i]);
    }
```

This piece of code is inside a function with this prototype (too big to paste here):

```
void insererCharDansTab2D(char ***tab, int *taillex, int *tailley, int posx, int posy, char c)
```

I wrote a comment where the segmentation fault appears. Thanks mates!

Comment: _sigh_ Thereis no 2D array in your code. A pointer is not an array! And being a 3-star C programmer is not a compliment.

Comment: `*tab[*taillex] = malloc(*tailley * sizeof(char));` --> `(*tab)[*taillex - 1] = malloc(*tailley * sizeof(char));`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks a lot that works! I'm stupid ahah that was so evident...

Comment: You cannot realloc a 2D array without risking corruption of the existing data.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit ???? I learned that the computer will try to find another place in the memory to put the new array.

Comment: @greenpoisononeTV An up-vote if you can show me the 2D array in this post's code.  I see pointers to pointers and arrays  of pointers

Comment: @chux  In fact pointers to pointers is a 2D array.

Comment: @greenpoisononeTV think about it.  After the realloc/copy, all the original data will be there, but not in the places you expect...

Comment: 'pointers to pointers is a 2D array' no, it is not.

Comment: I you have a 1d array of pointers that points each other to other 1d arrays...

Comment: @greenpoisononeTV Exactly... so you have a lot of 1D arrays, not a 2D array.

Comment: The solution gived by @BLUEPIXY  is only working for arrays with a size greater than 10...

Comment: @greenpoisononeTV: But that's not a 2D *array*.  In an array, all elements are *contiguous*.  An array of pointers to other arrays is not *contiguous*.

Comment: @Dmitri OK so It represents a 2D arrray no?

Comment: @John Bode ok ok ok

Comment: So how can i call it in my question's title?

Comment: @greenpoisononeTV: Yes, you can *index* it like a 2D array, but if you need to treat it as a stream of bytes (say for serialization purposes), then it's not the same thing as a 2D array.

Comment: Example:  `char a2d[3][4]` is a [2D array](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+a2d%5B3%5D%5B4%5D).  `char **ptr2` is a [pointer to pointer to char](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+a2d%5B3%5D%5B4%5D)

Comment: @chux  yeah but i can get a value like this : `(*tab)[*taillex][i]`. Is it not the same?

Comment: @greenpoisononeTV `8.0/2.0` and `8/2` both have the same _value_ of 4, but are not the same type.

Comment: OK I understand what you mean... then who can help me?

Comment: With a 2D array, `&arr[0][0]`, `&arr[0]`, and the decay of `arr` will all be the same address (but different pointer types).  With what you have, they'll be different because your version has several 1D arrays in different areas of memory... your version also has to store the individual row addresses in another array, which isn't needed for a real 2D array.

Comment: No idea to solve the issue?

Comment: Did you look at the duplicate suggested?  It has an answer that should solve your issue.

Comment: OK I found from mylself that's good.. Issue solved! Thanks for all mates! ;)